# Using Python to Display a particular value through key in Json file

Tags: python, json

I used python to get a json response from a website ,the json file is  as follows:

```
{

"term":"albany",
"moresuggestions":490,
"autoSuggestInstance":null,
"suggestions":[
    {
        "group":"CITY_GROUP",
        "entities":[
            {
                "geoId":"1000000000000000355",
                "destinationId":"1508137",
                "landmarkCityDestinationId":null,
                "type":"CITY",
                "caption":"<span class='highlighted'>Albany</span>, Albany County, United States of America",
                "redirectPage":"DEFAULT_PAGE",
                "latitude":42.650249,
                "longitude":-73.753578,
                "name":"Albany"
            },
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {}
        ]
    },
    {},
    {},
    {}
]

}
```

I used the following script to display the values according to a key:

```
import json
a =['']
data = json.loads(a)
print data["suggestions"]
```

This displays everything under 'suggestions' from the json file, however If I want to go one or two more level down,it throws an error.For Eg. I wanted to display the value of "caption", I searched for the solution but could not find what I need.I even tried calling :

```
print data["suggestions"]["entities"]
```

But the above syntax throws an error.What am  I missing here?

Comment: You are missing a `"` after `entities` in the last expression.

Comment: that a typo here,it doesn't help in the main code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data["suggestions"]` is a list of dictionaries. You either need to provide an index (ie `data["suggestions"][0]["entities"]`) or use a loop:

```
for suggestion in data["suggestions"]:
    print suggestion["entities"]
```

Keep in mind that `"entities"` is also a list, so the same will apply:

```
for suggestion in data["suggestions"]:
    for entity in suggestion["entities"]:
        print entity["caption"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see data within suggestions, is an array, so you should read like below:

`print data["suggestions"][0]["entities"]`

Answer (score 0):

"Suggestion" key holds a list of dicts.

You can access it like this though if the positions of dictionary remain intact.
`data["suggestions"][0]["entities"][0]["caption"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
print data["suggestions"][0]["entities"][0]["caption"]
```